# When a kafka consumer instance change group.id dynamical when the server restart

Tags: apache-kafka

When a kafka consumer instance restart and when its consumer group.id is changing in each restart. Is it fine to have this behaviour or will it impact kafka performance?

What will be the least value that we can provide for 'log.retention.ms' properties.

Answer (score 0):

In this case (changing group id after each resturt) will very well lead to reprocessing of your past data. Is it the desired behaviour?

Usually the group.id remains the same after consumer restart in order to store offsets for the group. Otherwise the new created consumer group (after restart) will continue processing regarding the `auto.offset.reset` configuration parameter.

Keeping group.id the same is the standard bahaviour.

Comment: Suppose I have 100+ consumer instace running on cloud compute and I am using hostname as the group.id but when server start it will change. So There is no problem if it start reading from beginning. but just trying to understand will it impact the kafka performance when a new consumer groups are getting created? what will happen to the old consumer group which was already created with previous group.id?

Comment: Why do you even use the consumer group when it seems you don't need it. You can simply use standalone consumers which are not assigned to any consumer group. As already said, using the same consumer group is the usual way. But it is not mandatory - you can handle the partition assignments your self and not use any consumer group.

Comment: If each consumer has different group.id, then none of your consumers are in same group.

Comment: Yes I want consumers to be different group.No I do not want to use partition assignment. I am trying to broadcast the messages to all consumer instances(consumer groups) when there is message in the topic. Just trying to understand is there is any impact on kafka if consumer group.id change when instances restart.

Comment: When I mean to say 100+ consumer instance that means 100+ servers and each will be part of different consumer group so that it will read same messages from a topic.